# how to convert an InMemoryUploadedFile upload to cloudinary in Django=1.11 using cloudinary.uploader.upload()

Tags: django, file-upload, base64, cloudinary

1. I am trying to upload an image file to cloudinary which I have sent from my django template to a function in views.py
2. The file is in request.FILES['image']

   ```
           cloudinary.config(
               cloud_name="p*****",
               api_key="33************",
               api_secret="4***-S***_o*********"
           )
           img_obj = request.FILES['image']
           cloudinary_response = cloudinary.uploader.upload(img_obj)
           image_url = cloudinary_response['url']
   ```
3. Printing img_obj gives the name of the image (Like :  "tree.jpg")
4. cloudinary upload doc is as follows https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload
5. The type of img_obj is InMemoryUploadedFile. Now is there a way to convert it to base64 or somthing like that so I can upload.
6. Or any other solution ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode Base64 Django ImageField Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179539/encode-base64-django-imagefield-stream)

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

1. `img_obj.file` is the actual file object, so you could try uploading that directly.
2. Since an `InMemoryUploadedFile` is a subclass of `File`, you can also just `open(mode='rb')` the file, using standard python file io functions.
3. Or you can try `img_obj.file.read()`

I would go for the second option:

```
import base64

with img_obj.open("rb") as image_file:
     encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

Comment: This should solve the problem. But unfortunately doing this raise an exception __exit__

Comment: can you show a backtrace? what's exactly the exception?